# Can "sans" be used in this manner?

Tags: word-usage

I was wondering if the word sans is correctly used in the following sentences: He was broke sans a few dollars. He was naked sans a shirt. Can it be used in more ways than simply the word without?

Comment: Do you think you could be confusing *sans* with *save* somehow? they're spelled similarly and memory can play strange tricks. Both of the following work: *He was broke save a few dollars. He was naked save a shirt.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I be using sans, anyway?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/480437/when-should-i-be-using-sans-anyway) Also [Is “sans” a drop-in replacement for “without”?
](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48748/is-sans-a-drop-in-replacement-for-without) and [When using the French word “sans” in an English sentence, should I use italics?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222491/when-using-the-french-word-sans-in-an-english-sentence-should-i-use-italics)

Comment: Have you looked up *sans* in a dictionary? Are you trying to say "He was naked *without* a shirt" (i.e. he's not really naked, he's wearing e.g. pants & shoes but he's *missing* a shirt) or "He was naked *except for* a shirt" (i.e. a shirt is the *only* thing he's wearing)?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of sans is simply **without**, see for example [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sans). They also provide some examples of use:

> She went to the party sans her husband.
>
> anyone sans shirt will not be allowed in the restaurant

Similarly, the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sans) has:

> *humorous, literary*
>
> Without.
>
> ‘*a picture of Maughan sans specs*’

So I'm not sure that your usage would be understood. You presumably mean "naked *except* for a shirt" in your second example, not "naked *without* a shirt".

Comment: He might be understood in 1650, where the word was used to mean "with the exception of" (OED), but that's archaic: 1659   J. Evelyn Let. 3 Sept. in Diary & Corr. (1852) III. 119   All play interdicted, sans bowls, chess, &c.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin If the OP edits the question to indicate they have a time machine ...

Comment: @JamesRandom They did, a week ago (but it was reverted next month).